# Hotkey to toggle display settings on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, hotkeys, display-settings

for a presentation I have to use two different display settings. For Keynote I want to see the presenters view on my laptop and the beamer should just show the slides. In between there are livedemos which require a resolution of 1024x768 and the screen to be mirrored.

So, I once discovered a hotkey to swap the current display settings with the ones I had before, but I cannot remember it and do not find it with google.

Does anybody know this hotkey or another easy way to archieve this?

Kind regards,

Nils

Comment: you want to toggle the resolution only?

Comment: Maybe this links help you
https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8355/switchresx
https://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/13375/displayconfigx

Comment: Also this one http://www.quickresapp.com/

Comment: I think you must try here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59075/how-to-set-screen-resolution-with-a-keyboard-shortcut-on-retina-mbp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the keyboard shortcut that toggles mirroring displays, it's command-F1 (or fn-command-F1).

Comment: Ah, that's what I meant, thx a lot!